# Is my mathematical representation of search in binary search tree correct?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, trees, recurrence-relation, recursion

You are given the `root` of a binary search tree (BST) and an integer `val`.

Find the node in the BST that the node's value equals `val` and return the subtree rooted with that node. If such a node does not exist, return `null`.

I have came up with a recursive solution in python, but I also want to document down the mathematical representation. I came up with the following, am I correct notation wise?

$$
f(v, x) =
\begin{cases}
      \emptyset & \text{if } v = \emptyset \\
      f\Big(\ell(v), x\Big) & \text{if } g(v) > x \\
      f\Big(r(v), x\Big) & \text{if } g(v) < x \\
      v & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

where

- $\emptyset$ is the empty tree, or `None` in Python
- $v$ is a node in the tree
- $\ell(v)$ is the left child of $v$
- $r(v)$ is the right child of $v$
- $g(v)$ is the value of node $v$, and $x$ is the target value to search for.

In this formulation, the function $f$ takes two arguments: a node $v$ and a
target value $x$. The function $\ell(v)$ returns the left child of the node $v$
and $r(v)$ returns the right child. Depending on the comparison of the value of
node $v$ and the target $x$, the function $f$ recursively calls itself on either
the left child or the right child of $v$. If $v$ is empty, it returns
$\emptyset$. If the value of node $v$ equals the target $x$, it returns $v$
itself. This function could be seen as a search algorithm on a binary tree.

Comment: This seems quite correct. $\text{otherwise}$ is also $v\ne\emptyset\land g(v)=x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Thanks for confirming, will the notation be more confusing if I replace $\ell(v)$ and $r(v)$ with $v_{\ell}$ and $v_r$?

Comment: IMO, this is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct, but it could be made more readable.

$$
search(node, val) =
\begin{cases}
      \emptyset & \text{if } node = \emptyset \\
      search(node.left, val) & \text{if } node.val > val \\
      search(node.right, val) & \text{if } node.val < val \\
      node & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$